# google maps route returning cyrillic letter for some languages

Tags: android, routes, maps

I want to get all city names in the route and send it to my PHP server. But I have problem when the device is in Serbian language it returns me Cyrillic letters.

After fetching url, downloading url I parse my result so I get

```
List<HashMap<String, Double>> steps;
```

It is a list of (lat, lng) of all steps in route. Then I do this:

```
String cityName="";

    LinkedHashSet<String> cities = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (int i=0; i<steps.size(); i++) {
        List<Address> address = gcd.getFromLocation(steps.get(i).get("lat"),
                steps.get(i).get("lng"), 1);
        if (address.get(0).getLocality() != null)
            cityName = address.get(0).getLocality();
        else if (address.get(0).getSubAdminArea() != null)
            cityName = address.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
        cities.add(cityName);

    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far, which is returning cyrillic letters?

Comment: I edited my post with code.